# PHP: Fire a tracking pixel before the header redirect

Tags: php, tracking

Here's my setup:

1. The visitor lands on page A, and a cookie is placed
2. The visitor lands on page B (php), the tracking pixel is fired and a header redirect takes the user to another page: C

So I want to fire an image pixel and then redirect the visitor instantly.

This is how my pixel looks like:

```
img height="1" width="1" border="0" style="display: none;" src="http://TrackingDomainHere./gpx.php?amount="
```

So basically I am trying:
a. to show that image pixel on the page and redirect instantly to C
b. to load that url somehow (without redirecting to it) and then redirect instantly to C

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why use a tracking pixel? Just log the link before you `header("Location: ...")`. Otherwise you'll have to use javascript redirection to allow the pixel time to load before redirection

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix http headers with HTML content like that. So your redirection scheme will need either the meta refresh tag, or a javascript snippet.

The meta refresh tag won't wait for the image to load, so you will miss hits if you do the redirection too quickly. You can write the Javascript code in such a way that it will wait for the image to load, but to depend on JS is not always a good idea :)

Comment: Small note, you are welcome to put something like `header('Location: xxx');` followed by `echo '<img src="tracking">';` in your code, it will even appear to run. The browser will just ignore it however, and the image will never be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect with PHP if you want to output any content first since PHP can only redirect with headers and headers need to be sent before any content. You will have to either use other means of redirecting (HTML / javascript) or use a different means of tracking.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was using javascript before, but I thought PHP would be a better idea since a good portion of my visitors are on mobile devices.